# Get file path from ExtBase FileReference

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I'm working on a custom finisher for ext: Forms / Typo3 Forms.

I added an image upload input to the form. I can fetch the entered form values using `getFormValues()` of the forms context, however, this returns a `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` for image input types.

How do I resolve the file reference to an actual file path? I need to do some extra work on the file itself, before attaching it to an e-mail and sending it out via the Mail API.

Comment: `getPublicUrl()` should help you. Maybe, you have to transform it into an absolute path, but that should not be difficult.

Comment: @JulianHofmann thank you, sry for the late response. That worked out, mind posting it as an answer, so I can accept it? :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPublicUrl()` should help you.
Maybe, you have to transform it into an absolute path, but that should not be difficult.

Comment: For future seekers: You'll have to call `getOriginalResource()` first :)